# Use Hibernate createNativeQuery with TypedQuery for Integer.class

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to use Hibernate `TypedQuery` for a `NativeQuery` with Integer.class argument. Is it possible?

```
NativeQuery<Integer> query = session.createNativeQuery("select 1 from dual", Integer.class);
query.list(); //<--Error.  Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Integer
```

or

```
query.getResultList(); //<--Error. Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Integer
```

or

```
query.getSingleResult(); //<--Error. Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Integer
```

I've found some examples on Web that suggest, this is theoretically possible.

[see getTaskCount()](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=opensecuritycontroller/osc-core/osc-core-master/osc-server/src/main/java/org/osc/core/broker/service/persistence/JobEntityManager.java)

**Update 1:** I've updated the example.

**Update 2:** Add getSingleResult() example.

Answer (score 2):

The resultClass parameter only accepts entity classes.

Also, when using native queries you are never guaranteed what what the return type for numbers will be, so using Integer or Long in a typecast will often blow-up on you when it's `java.math.BigInteger`.

What you need to do is:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select 1 from dual");  
Number nval = (Number) query.getSingleResult(); 
Integer val = nval == null ? null : nval.intValue();
```

Or for a list:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select 1 from dual");
List<Number> l = (List<Number>) query.getResultList();
for (Number nval : l) {
    Integer val = nval == null ? null : nval.intValue();
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But have you seen an example link? They are using Long.class as resultClass parameter.

Comment: Now I see they are using `Query` and not `NativeQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

Second parameter of createNativeQuery() should be a mapped entity. Integer is not. So you have to do :

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select 1 from dual");  
Integer val = (Integer) query.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's not quite true. I can use `list()` on query with only 1 result. I've updated my answer.